# PHP scheduler without cron

Tags: php, scheduler

I want to run my php script for every 5 minutes. Here is my PHP code.

```
function call_remote_file($url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
set_time_limit(0);

$root='http://mywebsiteurl'; //remote location of the invoking and the working script

$url=$root."invoker.php";
$workurl=$root."script.php";

call_remote_file($workurl);//call working script
sleep(60*5);// wait for 300 seconds.
call_remote_file($url); //call again this script
```

I run this code once. It works perfectly, even after i close the entire browser window.

The problem is the stops working if i turn of my system's internet connect.

How to solve this problem. Please help me out.

Comment: You want to execute the script every 5 minutes? Why not a cron job?

Comment: why not cron? and I don't understand why you are surprised it stops calling a script from your computer if your computer is not connected to the network.

Comment: My guess is he/she doesn't have access to cron on the host.

Comment: This should really be solved with a cronjob as others have mentioned. If your host doesn't support it then consider an alternative remote cron source such as http://www.setcronjob.com/

Comment: Thanks for the information @Treffynnon. I have created a cron job using setcronjob.com

Answer (score 1):

While I wouldn't really recommend doing this for something critical (you're going to have stability issues), this could work:

```
function call_remote_file($url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
set_time_limit(0);


$root='http://mywebsiteurl'; //remote location of the invoking and the working script

$url=$root."invoker.php";
$workurl=$root."script.php";

while(true)
{
    call_remote_file($workurl);//call working script
    sleep(60*5);// wait for 300 seconds.
}
```

Another way would be to call it from the command line using `exec()`:

```
function call_remote_file($url){
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);   
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
}
set_time_limit(0);


$root='http://mywebsiteurl'; //remote location of the invoking and the working script

$url=$root."invoker.php";
$workurl=$root."script.php";

call_remote_file($workurl);//call working script
sleep(60*5);// wait for 300 seconds.
exec('php ' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```

You should really use cron though if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

The above code is ok but if you want to add multiple scripts to run at different intervals then the coding becomes far more complicated.

If you try [phpjobscheduler](http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk/) (open source so free to use) it provides an interface to add, modify and remove scripts to run.